# CASE WHEN expression in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have built a CASE WHEN expression to show me when someone has no system transaction in the system under their user id for anything greater then 15 minutes.

```
  case
    when MOD_DATE_TIME > prior MOD_DATE_TIME+(1/96) 
         and user_id = prior user_id 
    then round((MOD_DATE_TIME - prior MOD_DATE_TIME)*1440,2)
    else null
  end as TIME_GAP
```

That above is the case when statement only. The full query is below:

```
 select
  user_id, MENU_OPTN_NAME, MOD_DATE_TIME,
  case
    when MOD_DATE_TIME > prior MOD_DATE_TIME+(1/96) and user_id = prior user_id then round((MOD_DATE_TIME - prior MOD_DATE_TIME)*1440,2)
    else null
  end as TIME_GAP
from
  (select
     ptt.user_id, MENU_OPTN_NAME, ptt.MOD_DATE_TIME,
     row_number() over (partition by ptt.user_id order by ptt.MOD_DATE_TIME) seq
   from PROD_TRKG_TRAN ptt
     join cd_master cm on
       ptt.cd_master_id = cm.cd_master_id
   Where
     MENU_OPTN_NAME = 'Cycle Cnt {Reserve}' --CHANGE BASED ON WHAT YOUR TRACKING... MENU NAMES AT THE BOTTOM
     and ptt.user_id = 'LLEE1' --CHANGE BASED ON WHO YOU WANT TO TRACK FOR A GAP...
     and cm.cd_master_id =
       (select cd_master_id
        from cd_master
        where
          co = '&CO'
          and div = '&DIV')
     and ptt.create_date_time >=
/*Today*/ trunc(sysdate)
--/*This Week*/              trunc(sysdate-(to_char(sysdate,'D')-1))
     --/*This Month*/            trunc(sysdate)-(to_char(sysdate,'DD')-1)
     --/*Date Range*/            '&FromDate' and ptt.create_date_time-1 < '&ToDate'
     --group by ptt.user_id
)cc
CONNECT BY
  user_id = prior user_id
  and seq = prior seq+1
start with
  seq = 1
```

What I want the query to do is in the CASE WHEN clause. I want it to account for the shift start time being 4pm, so if they don't do anything till 4:41PM then I would see that listed as a 41 min gap.

Comment: So what's wrong here? This `case` works fine, I [tested it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=185441cccaf0ea9a6106e86ed4cc2ee3). You can rewrite this query using `lag()` but `case` will be similiar. You want to sum these gaps for defined shifts or show only rows having gaps? Please specify your requirement.

Comment: I would like it to account for the shift start time being 4pm, so for example if they don't have anything in the system until 4:41pm then it would show me a 41 min gap from there start time. or would this require a separate case when expression.